# Find the location of data base file that gets created when a user is created in django application

Tags: django, postgresql, kubernetes

In a Django application with PostgreSQL as database, where do the users get stored? Any file where can I check the users info...basically where will be the .db file stored in Django?

Comment: please let know community about usefulness of answer and accept/upvote it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default location for storage in PostgreSQL is `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) provides the Secret object to store sensitive data, which can be created using i.e. the declarative file specification.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  user: ZGphbmdv
  password: MWEyNmQxZzI2ZDFnZXNiP2U3ZGVzYj9lN2Q=
```

`User` field as well as `password` field contains base64 encoded strings where the encoding can be generated from the command line by running:

```
$ echo -n "<string>" | base64
```

The Secret object is then added to the kubernetes cluster using:

```
$ kubectl apply -f postgres/secrets.yaml
```

By default, Django uses the sqlite database configuration. To update the database configuration, the following modifications needs to be made to the DATABASES variable in the `settings.py` file. Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#database).

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'kubernetes_django',
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT', 5432)
     }
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py file, there is a variable called DATABASES. It is a dict, and one of its keys is default, which maps to another dict. This subdict has a key, NAME, which has the path of the  database.

This is an example of a project

```
CURRENT_DIR= '/path/'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.db',
        'NAME': CURRENT_DIR+ '/database.db', # <- The path
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have smthg like 'NAME' : os.os.environ.get('DB_NAME','test'), i think some environment variable is set

Comment: Yes @Lisa just `print (os.os.environ.get('DB_NAME','test'))` will give you the path

Comment: Actually i am running my django application as kubernetes containers, jst now got to know that all the data stored will be in  PersistentVolume on a cluster, not sure where to get the exact path

Comment: @Lisa what's in os.os.environ.get('DB_NAME','test')? Did you try to print?